# How markers can result in conflicts?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, bison, yacc, lex

Why does a  grammar with the following rule result in a conflict?

```
    Statement   |   IF  {...} LP BoolExp RP %prec IFX  Statement { ... }
                |       ...
```

The IFX terminal is for the standard trick for resolving dangling else. I think that this is somehow related.
Removing the first marking removes the conflict.

The message bison outputs is:

> warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts: $@2: /* empty */

Comment: I hope this is relevant and useful: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bison/2001-10/msg00011.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

([Answered in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@sarnold wrote:

> I hope this is relevant and useful: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bison/2001-10/msg00011.html/

However SO deprecates web link only answers. So I summarise here.
The link is to a list reply entitled **"Shift reduce errors due to embedded actions"** by @Hans Aberg. In outline it suggests:

> The best way around this problem is probably to collect the semantic
>   information that A and B produces and then use that when appyling C or D.